# MySQL query to concat prefix to existing value in a field

Tags: mysql, concatenation

My table structure is as follows,

```
ID  Name    Source
1   John    first.jpg
2   Doe second.jpg
3   Mary    third.jpg
4   Kurian  four.jpg
```

I would like to update the "Source" by prepending with the host and primary key as follows

```
http://example.com/1/first.jpg
http://example.com/2/second.jpg
http://example.com/3/third.jpg
http://example.com/4/four.jpg
```

tried with CONCAT("http://example.com/"+id,Source) but fails with Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Any suggestion will be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET Source = CONCAT('http://example.com/', ID, '/', Source);
```

**Result**

```
| ID |   Name |          Source                 |
|----|--------|---------------------------------|
|  1 |   john |  http://example.com/1/first.jpg |
|  2 |    Doe | http://example.com/2/second.jpg |
|  3 |   Mary |  http://example.com/3/third.jpg |
|  4 | Kurian | http://example.com/4/fourth.jpg |
```

Comment: @Steve yes it will work, `CONCAT` function will convert numeric ID to String and then concatenate it with other arguments passed in this function.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this

```
 SELECT CONCAT("http://example.com/" , CONCAT(ID , CONCAT("/" , Source))) FROM table_name;
```

or simply

```
 SELECT CONCAT("http://example.com/" ,ID , "/" , Source) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in sql but the easiest way is to create a php script in which you create an array with the rows of the table
Then use the dot si tax to concat ID with the domain name and the source, something like:

```
$newval = ‘{$table[“ID”]}’ .“/Domainname.com/” . ’{$table[“Source”]}’;
```

Where $table is a variable storing the associative array of the table

And then make a new query in which you override the source column for each row in the table array

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

UPDATE table_Name 
SET Source = concat(concat(CONCAT('http://example.com/',ID),'/'),source);